# Bundle items issue in api response

Tags: magento-2.1, api, bundled-product

I have one bundle product with some options. When I change status or available stock of simple product,

this is not reflected in bundle product. this disble product is showing in api response,

Comment: Have you done reindex and cache clean ?

Comment: yes,i done both things.But this disble product is showing in api response.

Comment: plz guide me...

Comment: Anybody tell me what is issue in this api?